# alpine linux -- autossh (missing)

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux, autossh

I need to be able to :

-- `RUN apk add --no-cache autossh`

for migrating my project into alpine linux from ubuntu

I'm getting an error while building the Dockerfile.. any workarounds?
I cannot get rid of the autossh requirement as I need this to connect to me compose db.

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  autossh (missing):
    required by: world[autossh]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache autossh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package *autossh* is in the *community* repository and only *edge* branch, as you can [check on pkgs.alpinelinux.org](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=autossh&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=). Alpine has only *main* from a stable branch in `/etc/apk/repositories` by default, so to install package from another repository and branch, you have to add it here, e.g.:

```
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk update
```

- https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Aports_tree
- https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Enable_Community_Repository

Comment: thank you! It was pretty non-obvious to me re: search. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Please try running apk update before that in docker file. Hope it works

Comment: Agreed. autossh is an alpine package: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/autossh so update will probably get it for you